# Accessing iBeacon advertisement data when using private frameworks

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I need to access raw advertisement data of iBeacons (not AltBeacons). The app does not need to be deployed into the AppStore, thus using private frameworks is ok. I have tried to use [BeeTee](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee), which shows how to use `BluetoothManager.framework`, but it does not discover any devices (tested on iPhone 6, iOS 8.4 and iPod Touch, iOS 8.1.1).

Which other options are available?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do this.  iOS has security blocks that prevent reading the raw advertisement bytes of iBeacons using CoreBluetooth or other means.  There are no known workarounds.

I documented my attempts to find a way around this in a [blog post here.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html)  For what it's worth, you can do this on OSX using CoreBluetooth and on Android devices using built-in bluetooth scanning APIs. It's just iOS that blocks decoding the raw advertising bytes of iBeacon advertisements.